# Computing multivariate normal integral over box region in SciPy

Tags: r, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution, scipy.stats

I am trying to evaluate the multivariate normal distribution to get the probability that `1 < z1 < 2.178` and `2.178 < z2 < inf`. The mean of the distribution is zero, all variances are 1, and the covariance is `1/sqrt(2)`.

In `R`, I get the correct results via:

```
library(mnormt)
sadmvn(lower=c(1, 2.178), upper=c(2.178, Inf), mean=0, varcov=matrix(c(1, 1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2), 1),2, 2))
```

In SciPy, I am trying:

```py
from scipy import stats
cov = np.array([[1, 1 / np.sqrt(2)], [1 / np.sqrt(2), 1]])
d = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=np.array([0, 0]), cov=cov)
d.cdf([2.178, np.inf]) - d.cdf([1, 2.178])
```

but this gives something around 0.14 instead of the correct result ~0.0082. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lower_limit` parameter of the [`multivariate_normal.cdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) method to compute the CDF within a hyperrectangle with corners `lower_limit` and `x` (the first positional argument).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
cov = np.array([[1, 1 / np.sqrt(2)], [1 / np.sqrt(2), 1]])
d = stats.multivariate_normal(mean=np.array([0, 0]), cov=cov)
d.cdf([2.178, np.inf], lower_limit=[1, 2.178])
# 0.00820893693689204
```

It looks like `lower_limit` and `x` of `multivariate_normal` correspond with `lower` and `upper` of `sadmvn`, respectively.

The reason why your original approach did not work is that when `cdf` is called without `lower_limit`, the lower limit of integration it is assumed to be `[-np.inf, -np.inf]`. Therefore, your code was calculating the difference between the CDFs of two hyperectangles, each with lower limit `[-np.inf, -np.inf]`. This idea works in 1D, but in 2+ dimensions, this is not the same as the CDF within a single hyperrectangle from corner `[1, 2.178]` to corner `[2.178, np.inf]`.

For example, in the diagram below, the area enclosed within the rectangle defined by points A and B is not the same as the difference between the areas of the blue and red rectangles.

[image]